# Set content-encoding to specific files via aws command

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I deploy static application by aws command.
I copy all files from my folder to s3 bucket by this command :

```
aws s3 sync C:\app s3://myBucket
```

I want to set content-encoding to gzip just to js,jpg,and html files. 
I succeed to do it for all folder by this command : `--content-encoding gzip`
How can I do it just for the specific files type ?

Answer (score 11):

This is old, but I needed to find a way to do this: I'm not using Cloudfront, and the proxy we are using doesn't handle gzip... so:

1. Exclude all files
2. Include individual file types as needed
3. Set the appropriate encoding/options

Below I'm also adding access control and cache-control, and deleting any files in s3 not present in the local directory

I've separated the JS/CSS from all of the images, html but that is probably not necessary.

I did however have a lot of trouble by not explicitly setting the content-encoding/cache for each individual --include, so I've set it like below to make it clearer.

The AWS docs that I could find don't mention any of this stuff

```
aws s3 sync ./dist/ s3://{bucket} \
--exclude "*" \
--include "static/*.ico" --acl "public-read" --cache-control no-cache \
--include "static/*.png" --acl "public-read" --cache-control no-cache \
--include "*.html" --acl "public-read" --cache-control no-cache \
--include "static/img/*.svg" --acl "public-read" --cache-control no-cache \
--delete \

aws s3 sync ./dist/ s3://{bucket} \
--exclude "*" \
--include "static/js/*.js" --acl "public-read" --cache-control  no-cache --content-encoding gzip \
--include "static/css/*.css" --acl "public-read" --cache-control no-cache --content-encoding gzip \
--delete \
```

Pretty neat little speed improvement for serving only from s3.

Comment: There is no need to set `--acl` and `--cache-control` for each file type as the last one is used for all of them.